# JAVA: How do I determine if the input is a palindrome?

Tags: java

Please use the method below.

I am trying to get rid of all white spaces, punctuations and make everything lowercase. Then I want to see whether the string is a palindrome (same when read from the front and back.

I can't figure it out.

````
public static void main(String[] args) {


        String word=null;
        String reverse="";
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a word or a phrase:");
        word = console.nextLine();

        word=word.replaceAll("\\s+",""); //removes white space
        word=word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", ""); //removes all punctuation
        word=word.toLowerCase();


        for(int i=word.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        reverse +=word.charAt(i);


        }

        for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(word);
        if(word.charAt(i) != reverse.charAt(i)) {
            System.out.println("Not a Palindrome");
        }else {
                System.out.println("Palindrome");```
````

Comment: No. It uses public static boolean.

Comment: That is just a minor thing, it's the actual code used to determine the palindrome you should look at and that question has several answers that are worthwhile to study. Or are you only looking for a copy/paste solution?

Comment: I don't know how to get rid of the public static boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two indices i and j, where i starts at 0-index and j starts at the end of array. Do i++ and j-- and at each iteration check if the element is same and when j>i you break the loop and say its palindrome or else it is not Palindrome.

You can do this iteratively or recursively.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can combine all of your *regular expressions* into one (first make the input lowercase, then eliminate everything not a lowercase letter). Second, you can eliminate building a temporary `String` to check if it's a palindrome; because you can iterate the characters in the `word` and check the front with the back. Like,

```
System.out.print("Please enter a word or a phrase:");
String word = console.nextLine().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
boolean palindrome = true;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length() / 2; i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(word.length() - i - 1)) {
        palindrome = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (!palindrome) {
    System.out.println("Not a Palindrome");
} else {
    System.out.println("Palindrome");
}
```

If you **decide** you want to reverse `word` anyway for a less efficient implementation. Use `StringBuilder`, because it can be done in one line (and I think it looks more readable).

```
System.out.print("Please enter a word or a phrase:");
String word = console.nextLine().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
if (!new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString().equals(word)) {
    System.out.println("Not a Palindrome");
} else {
    System.out.println("Palindrome");
}
```